# Where is object class in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Where is the object class in the source code of Python? If I run object.**module** says that is in the builtins module but I dont find it the file in my virtual environment. I want review this class in the source code.

```
In [1]: object.__module__                                                                                                                                                
Out[1]: 'builtins'
```

Comment: It's... builtin. In cpython, it's in C. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/object.c

Comment: @JeffMercado: You'd think that was the right file from the name, but `object` is actually in `Objects/typeobject.c`.

Comment: `Objects/object.c` is where the ["object protocol"](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html) functions are implemented.

Comment: @user2357112: Ah right... been a long while since I've had to look that the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already found out that the `object` class is in the `builtins` module. And like the name already reveals, this class is built-in. That means it's part of the Python interpreter. That's why you don't find it in your installed Python environment.

The official Python interpreter is called CPython, which is (again, like the name reveals) written in C. You can either download the source code from [downloads page](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/), or find the source code at [Github](https://github.com/python/cpython).

A Python `object` corresponds to a `PyBaseObject_Type` type in CPython. You can find the source code for its definition here:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in CPython but the object in Python are not defined in Python but in C. I find some files in the gitub repository:

- a folder [Objects](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Objects),
- a file [objects.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/object.c).

**Edit**
It seems my search was too light. As other answer told, the definition of `Object` class is in [typeobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c)

Answer (score -2):

Python 2 needed the object class, because it supported an older form of limited inheritance using the `class Classname:` syntax.  In Python3 `class Classname:` replaces the need for `class Classname(object):` to get full-fledged inheritance.

Comment: You're answering a completely different question from the one that was asked.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I try to answer the question they should be asking.

Comment: How do you know which question they should be asking?